Polymer functions not functioning after Angular 11 update from 10
The errors in the console after ng serve has compiled succesfully
These errors have just started to be thrown in angular 11. It was running fine in angular 8, 9, 10. This is recurrent on multiple micro services.
Polymer is being used inside of a bundle.html file and this is the first occurence.
//# sourceMappingURL=webcomponents-lite.js.map
</script>
<script>
  var Polymer = Polymer || {};
  Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>
<div hidden="" by-polymer-bundler="">

Note that I was following the official migration steps from Angular10 to 11
I updated the bower.json dependencies to their latest dependencies, since webcomponents-lite.js.map is inside of the bower_components folder. No luck.
I have applied the reccomendations from this
package.json
{
  "name": "hvdc-emd-ui-connectivity",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions@0.0.3",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "polymer-bundler --inline-scripts src/index.html>src/bundle.html | ng build",
    "prod-build": "polymer-bundler --inline-scripts src/index.html>src/bundle.html | ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^24.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^24.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-request-proxy": "^2.2.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "json-schema": "0.4.0",
    "tough-cookie": "4.1.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.35",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "qs": "6.10.3",
    "async": "2.6.4",
    "moment": "2.29.4"
  },
  "config": {
    "unsafe-perm": true
  }
}

